# Custom Map in Datamaps

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, topojson, datamaps

Hello I'm using d3 js with datamaps and I want to show the few countries of the world. I have checked the online forum for the help but not get cleared idea or response.

Source code :

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/0.4.4/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>

<script>
var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            HIGH: '#afafaf',
            LOW: '#123456',
            MEDIUM: 'blue',
            UNKNOWN: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
            defaultFill: 'green'
        },

        dataType: 'json', //for use with dataUrl, currently 'json' or 'csv'. CSV should have an `id` column
    dataUrl: null,
    geographyConfig: {
        dataUrl: null, //if not null, datamaps will fetch the map JSON (currently only supports topojson)
        hideAntarctica: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderOpacity: 1,
        borderColor: '#FDFDFD',
        popupTemplate: function(geography, data) { //this function should just return a string
          return '<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' + geography.properties.name + '</strong></div>';
        },
        popupOnHover: true, //disable the popup while hovering
        highlightOnHover: true,
        highlightFillColor: '#FC8D59',
        highlightBorderColor: 'rgba(250, 15, 160, 0.2)',
        highlightBorderWidth: 2,
        highlightBorderOpacity: 1
    },
        done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
                console.log(geography);
                var url = window.location.href;
                var arr = url.split("/");
                var result = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2]
                window.open(result+'/countries/view/'+geography.properties.name);
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

It'll display all the countries. but i want to show few country.
How can I pass the country list over there?
I think with the help of custom.json or topojson. I don't know. Let me know if you have any solution or guidance.

Comment: Why don't you use your own topojson that way its more customized

Comment: @Vinod Louis How can I create my own topojson  that I don't know

Comment: @Pratik you can follow this tutorial https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c#.ylaal2hmk I used the same once

Comment: How can I get the specific country file list? In that forum it's using http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_06_tract_500k.zip' for USA only.

Comment: once you have your geojson file goto http://mapshaper.org/ and edit it

Comment: I don't have geojson file

Comment: you can convert your shape file its in the tutorial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135346/discussion-between-pratik-and-vinod-louis).